# Plotly dash ignore NaN values

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I have some NaN values in my dataframe like this:

```
a|b|c|d
a1|NaN|c1|cd
a2|b2|c1|NaN
```

When I draw a parallel categories diagram, they are reflecting in the plot.How do I make them invisible in parallel categories diagram?
I use the following code:

```
fig = px.parallel_categories(df)

fig.show()
```

Comment: Can you please add a minimal example?

Comment: @Nils Hi.As you might already know,each parallel categories diagram has a component at different levels.For example,for my a column in dataframe,I want to remove all NaN values in parallel categories diagram

Comment: @SriTest Test, were you able to find an answer?  My plot is grouping the nulls into their own section in each level of the plot.  This is making the plot look overly busy.